# Grab back of string until terminating character

Tags: python

I have a variable that currently stores a url address e.g. `user/Syntaf` , and what I need to do is extract the nickname from the url.

So given `next = user/Syntaf` I need to extract `Syntaf` into another variable from the string and leave `user`. How can I go about doing this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.search` method,

```
>>> import re
>>> next = 'user/Syntaf'
>>> m = re.search(r'\/(.*)$', next)
>>> m.group(1)
'Syntaf'
>>> result = m.group(1)
>>> result
'Syntaf'
```

It stores all the characters which are next to `/` upto the last character into a group(`group1`).  Print back the `group(1)` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Or more generally `'/([^/]*)$'` to grab anything after the *last* slash.

Comment: `re.search()`? is re a reference to a variable? Do I need to import something? my interpreter just gives `re not defined`

Comment: yep, you need to import re module. `import re`

Comment: `re.search` is a function from `re` module which is used to search for specific string in the input. If an match found, it return the matched string and got exited.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
nick = re.match(r'user/(\w+)', 'user/Syntaf').group(1)
```

Note that this version throws an exception if the string doesn't actually match your regex, if it's possible to get strings like `'chicken/duck'` you should check whether or not `re.match(r'user/(\w+)', s)` is None.